# Google Visualization Chart Stopped Working

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have created a dashboard which uses JSON data to create several different kinds of google visualization charts. This dashboard has been working perfectly for two years. Just in the past day or so, the column chart and the line chart give a "Cannot read property 'Do' of undefined" error while my tables and maps continue to work. I have checked all of the most recent records to make sure there is nothing that could be undefined and I have found no issues. I've checked my arrays in the console and they all look correct.  I've also checked the chart objects in the console just before drawing and they are properly populated, so I am stumped.  Can anyone help me figure out what could be happening?

Comment: try using a saved version instead of the `'current'` version, when loading google charts. --> `google.charts.load('50', { ...`

Comment: @WhiteHat I love you! Thank you! My dashboard was created by studying your answers here on SO to myself and others and I am so grateful.  This trick fixed it. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load google charts with a saved version (a.k.a. *Frozen Charts Version*)...

```
google.charts.load('50', {
```

when implementing a page or application,
always use a saved version of google charts.
this way, changes to the `'current'` version can't mess with your code.

you can find a list of the saved versions at the following link,
along with the changes that were implemented...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#version-history

Comment: Amazing. My google charts suddenly stopped working in April 2023 with the error message `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') ` , and I found the problem was a line setting the fontName to Roboto in the chart options. Removing this line solved the problem. I now understand that the problem was caused by Google updating the library.  I have implemented WhiteHat's solution in order to preempt any future problems.